# how to chop (truncate) long lines in bash output to fit in the screen with?

Tags: command-line, bash, shell, less

I love piping any output into `less -S` because it prints neatly without wrapping long lines of output into new lines (especially for tables). However, I wonder if there is a way to truncate long lines for anything that is printed directly in the terminal, with the option to seeing the chopped portion by using the right arrow key.

Comment: That would probably need to be a "terminal" (e.g. similar to rxvt) having the same "-S" mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For many terminals,

```
setterm -linewrap off
```

should do the trick for the truncation.

There seems to be a java implementation of a terminal with a horizontal scrollbar. It is called [Terminator](https://github.com/software-jessies-org/jessies/wiki/Terminator) Haven't tried it myself.

Comment: And many terminals then discard the excessive text, I think. Can you name terminals "with the option to see the chopped portion"?

Comment: Sorry, missed that requirement. Added terminator.